# How can I change the URL path to folder in server using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to change the URL path to a folder using `.htaccess` like the format below:

```
http://example.com/src/home/
```

To

```
http://example.com/home/
```

Any Help ?

Comment: You should instead set your documentRoot to /src/ in your apache conf, then is would automatically do want you want.

Comment: thanks for comment, but i have another folders like : config, assets in the same path to src folder, if i change documentRoot how i can access to others folders

Answer (score 3):

Using .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ src/home/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: its working good thanks, but if i access to /src/home want to be redirect to home/ :)

Comment: I think it should also be possible.This line: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means if the file doesn't exist, then rewrite

Comment: @MnaouarMarouane Presumably you are already linking to `/home` in your application and the redirect would only be for SEO purposes?

Answer (score 0):

If I should design the structure, I would do it like this:

```
/
/src/
/src/public/assets/css/all.css
/src/public/assets/js/all.js
/src/public/index.php
/src/public/.htaccess
/src/app/ <= All you classes, php files and functions
```

Set documentRoot to /src/public

Your index.php is now your entry point and you can load all your classes, setup a MVC pattern or anything you like.

All files that you use in your project in referenced by the server root / all assets that the browser is supposed to use, like css and js you put those in the public.

If you want you images to be secure, you could load them via a php file that takes them from outside the public folder.

Hope this all makes sense?